# Graphiql not working due of security - Spring for GraphQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, spring-graphql

I'm trying to use graphiql UI but due of Spring Security, I receive 401.

What's the way to keep /graphql endpoint secured but let /graphiql request to graphql endpoint?

I'm on Spring Boot 3.1.4 and Spring For Graphql 1.2.3

If I permitall /graphql it works but I loss security. I Tried also to put /vendor/** in permitAll but no luck.

Comment: what's your security configuration? authentication mechanism? what's the security behavior you're expecting?

Comment: Hi Brian, the security mechanism is with key cloak and Spring-Security. I expect that when I use graphiql UI, I can query the endpoint that is secured. Actually I can't due that graphiql isn't aware of ClientId and ClientSecret (as for swagger, in example).

Answer (score 0):

If your application is using a specific authentication mechanism (like OAuth) that requires additional data to be sent along the GraphQL requests, this needs to be taken care of in GraphiQL as well.

The first step is to ensure that the `/graphiql` endpoint is considered in the security configuration.

Then you'll probably need to either manually enter the authentication information in the "headers" panel of GraphiQL. You can also consider building your own GraphiQL integration (just like GitHub does with their authentication). See [this GraphiQL issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/issues/1771) to get more details.

The default GraphiQL integration in Spring GraphQL is mostly meant for development purposes and is not meant to support all production uses cases.